# Triple single quote strings in Groovy - Should the resulting string contain extra spaces?

Tags: grails, groovy

If I use the following groovy code:

```
description: '''Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers
                of America as we hone our skills and ham it up
                a bit.  You can show off your programming chops
                while trying to win a year's supply of pork
                chops in our programming challenge.

                Come and join us in historic (and aromatic),
                Austin, Minnesota.  You'll know when you're
                there!'''
```

Isn't groovy supposed to create one long string with only single spaces between lines (meaning that the spaces between lines will not be kept)?  The resulting string would be:

Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers of America as we hone our skills and ham it up a bit... etc

The string I got contained all the spaces between lines.  Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 10):

Since Groovy 1.7.3:

```
def description = '''\
          Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers
          of America as we hone our skills and ham it up
          a bit.  You can show off your programming chops
          while trying to win a year's supply of pork
          chops in our programming challenge.

          Come and join us in historic (and aromatic),
          Austin, Minnesota.  You'll know when you're
          there!'''.stripIndent()
```

Answer (score 5):

Lee's right, triple quoted strings aren't given any special treatment, but because you're using groovy, it's easy enough to get the behavior you want:

```
def description = '''Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers
                 of America as we hone our skills and ham it up
                 a bit.  You can show off your programming chops
                 while trying to win a year's supply of pork
                 chops in our programming challenge.

                 Come and join us in historic (and aromatic),
                 Austin, Minnesota.  You'll know when you're
                 there!'''

description.split("\n").collect { it.trim() }.join(" ")
```

prints:

```
Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers of America as we hone our skills and ham it up a bit.  You can show off your programming chops while trying to win a year's supply of pork chops in our programming challenge.  Come and join us in historic (and aromatic), Austin, Minnesota.  You'll know when you're there!
```

If you're looking for additional formatting, you might want to check out [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) syntax and the [MarkdownJ library](http://markdownj.org/).  I actually just released a [Grails Markdown plugin](http://bitbucket.org/tednaleid/grails-markdown/wiki/Home) yesterday that will take markdown formatted text and turn it into HTML for a GSP.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's expected. Triple quotes is just a multi-line string, there's no magic to detect and remove indentation.

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on the previous answer, if you do this:

```
def description = '''\
Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers
of America as we hone our skills and ham it up
a bit.  You can show off your programming chops
while trying to win a year's supply of pork
chops in our programming challenge.

Come and join us in historic (and aromatic),
Austin, Minnesota.  You'll know when you're
there!'''
```

the text format is pretty easy to work with. A backslash () immediately followed by end of line (EOL) will be swallowed. (See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Groovy+String+Handling)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to get rid of the extra white spaces:

```
description.replaceAll('\\s+', ' ')
```

or

```
(description =~ /\s+/).replaceAll(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just forgo the formatting requirement, and format it like

```
description: '''Join the Perl programmers of the Pork Producers
of America as we hone our skills and ham it up
a bit.  You can show off your programming chops
while trying to win a year's supply of pork
chops in our programming challenge.

Come and join us in historic (and aromatic),
Austin, Minnesota.  You'll know when you're
there!'''
```

then you will get the desired string, without having to post-process it. It doesnt look too bad imho...